# How to use select method on nested model associations in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three models:

```
class Person
  has_many :houses
end

class House
  belongs_to :person
  has_many :appliances

  attr_accessible :address
end

class Appliance
  belongs_to :house

  attr_accessible :price
end
```

I want to use the 'select' method to fetch only the 'price' values such as the following:

```
Person.joins(:houses => :appliances).select('houses.appliances.price')
```

But the above didn't work. However, I tested a similar method like the one below that works:

```
Person.joins(:houses).select('houses.address')
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have `Appliances` class named in plural form?

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. It's just a typo. Sorry, I didn't see it while typing. I updated this just now.

Comment: Try `Person.joins(:houses => :appliances).select('appliances.price')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should work:

```
Person.joins(houses: :appliances).select('appliances.price')
```

Comment: It worked! Was stuck for hours now. Thanks so much :)